# C unit test frameworks with Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

Is CppUnit the only C/C++ unit test framework currently available for use with Sonar?

What would be involved in adding additional C/C++ unit testing frameworks? (e.g. how many lines of code is the CppUnit plugin, how reusable, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the unit test page: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Unit+Test+Support

From that page:

> The C++ Plugin parses xunit compliant format using the
>   sonar.cxx.xunit.reportPath. To use other formats, first they need to
>   be converted using the property sonar.cxx.xunit.xsltURL
>
> For convenience the following xsl are provided
>
> - boosttest-1.x-to-junit-1.0.xsl         For transforming Boost-reports
> - cpptestunit-1.x-to-junit-1.0.xsl      For transforming
> - CppTestUnit-reports cppunit-1.x-to-junit-1.0.xsl            For transforming CppUnit-reports

So packages that support xUnit format, like Google Test Framework, should be supported.  Otherwise, if they output xml they should be supportable by changing the xslt.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should better send your queries in Sonar's mailing lists : http://www.sonarsource.org/support/support/